# how I can fix this? python3.2

Tags: binary, ascii, python-3.2

I'm trying to finish a program that converts text2bin and bin2text among other things, but I have a problem with the bin2text function, but only with some characters.
This is the part that is giving me problems:

```
def bin2text(self):                 
  cadena2=' '

  self.ventana.caja1.text()
  split=[self.ventana.caja1.text()[x:x+8] for x in range(0,len(self.ventana.caja1.text()),8)]

   for i in splits:
       cadena2=cadena2+chr(int(i,2))

   self.ventana.caja2.setText(cadena2)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Invalid literal for int() with base 2 '100000 1.... '
```

on the line

```
cadena2=cadena2+chr(int(i,2))
```

(The ellipses dots aren't actually a part of the error but there's an arrow in the way in the figure)

when I try to go from binary to text, using "space" or any sign that the passing of ASCII to Bin, the number consists of six digits, I get the error. Seven or eight digit numbers work.

I need to know a how to add a  0 at the beginning of this series(**0**100000), to fix it

See figures below:
[image: no problem]

[image: with problem]

[image: this is the problem]

Comment: please copy-paste your code and errors instead of taking screen shots in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
splits = self.ventana.caja1.text().split() #split by whitespace

for i in splits:
   cadena2=cadena2+chr(int(i,2))
```

The problem is not the number of digits, the problem is the whitespace within the string you sent to 'int'